# Understanding Redis from MySQL use case

Tags: mysql, redis, data-migration, querying

I am new to Redis and trying to implement a thing with PHP and Redis.

I am just describing the scenario in MySQL, I am not migrating anything from MySQL to Redis.

Let's say I have a table, in which I will be storing user's daily consumption, with the following structure

```
 +-----------+------------+---------+
 |  user_id  |    date    |  count  |
 +-----------+------------+---------+
 |   123     | 2017-06-06 |   231   |
 |   123     | 2017-06-07 |   456   |
 |   124     | 2017-06-06 |   433   |
 |   124     | 2017-06-07 |   188   |
 +-----------+------------+---------+
```

The count column would be updated in the following manner, with every call

```
UPDATE `table` 
SET count = count + 12 
WHERE user_id = 123 AND date = 2017-06-06
```

After reading about Redis, I understand that there is no concept of tables in Redis and to store such data, I should be using keys in the following format :

```
(e.g. key user:123:date:2017-06-06)

127.0.0.1:6379> INCRBY user:123:date:2017-06-06 12
(integer) 12
127.0.0.1:6379> INCRBY user:123:date:2017-06-06 32
(integer) 44
```

So far so good.

Now the issues I am facing is with querying.
In MySQL, at the end of the month I can show users their consumption and billing by simply using the following query :

```
SELECT `date`,`count` FROM `table` WHERE `date` > 'some_date' AND `user_id` = 123
```

or

```
SELECT SUM(`count`),`user_id`,MONTH(date) GROUP BY `user_id`,MONTH(`date`)
```

But I am not sure how to do this in Redis, if I want to calculate for a single user, then it is easy as I know the format of key and have user_id, so I can create the key and fetch exact data I need

```
127.0.0.1:6379> GET user:123:date:2017-06-06 32
```

But is there something like or something similar

```
127.0.0.1:6379> GET user:*:date:*
```

Or is Redis not made for such type of queries and thing?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks
(or if you can direct me to some helpful documentation)

(Reason, I am implementing it in Redis and not MySQL is, there will be many increment queries per second, about hundreds and I thought Redis would be better for this. As the maximum time it will be only INCR query, and once or twice searching)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different ways you can store your data in redis that would help with querying.

If you stored each user in their own set, e.g.

```
HSET user:1234 date:2017-06-06 231
```

then it would be very easy to increment the counts:

```
HINCRBY user:1234 date:2017-06-06)
```

But more difficult to get dates by range (you'd need to retrieve the entire hash and then loop through it checking dates.)

If you stored each users date in a sorted set using epoch dates:

```
ZADD userdates:1234 1507317704 123
```

Then it would be easy to get a date range using ZRANGEBYSCORE, but harder to increment a score as you would need to retrieve the current score and then write it back.

You could also use a hybrid of the two, where you store dates in a sorted set, and use that to lookup dates in the hash. It depends on your data and if you know the dates in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Or is redis not made for such type of queries and thing?

That's the gist of it, but you can either a) maintain your own indices for searching - read more at https://redis.io/topics/indexes, or b) use http://redisearch.io to do it.